Subscription set up in App Store Connect. The price can be displayed correctly in Xcode preview, but it cannot be displayed in real-device testing
Three subscription items are set in App Store Connect: consumable item (monthly/annual), non-consumable item (lifetime). The price can be displayed normally when previewing in Xcode, and clicking the subscription button can trigger the purchase pop-up window. However, when running on a real device or in a version released to TestFlight, the price cannot be displayed normally and the purchase pop-up window cannot be triggered. Suspecting it is a problem caused by environment switching. Xcode preview should be in the Xcode environment (the title on the upper left corner of the purchase pop-up window shows Xcode), while real device testing is in the sandbox environment. But I have set up a sandbox account in App Store Connect and logged in to the sandbox account in the App Store settings of the real device. The problem still exists.

Changing the build configuration to release in scheme is ineffective.
Checked whether the product ID in App Store Connect matches that in the code and confirmed the match.
Checked distribution mode is App Store in scheme.


You’ll have to introduce proper error handling so you can see what the issue is.

Also, what is the state of your in app purchase products in App Store Connect?
